# Cannot Get Django to Search Database for a User Inputted Model Object Attribute

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-models, django-views

I'd really appreciate anyone helping me understand how to properly search model object attributes in django. First, I ask for an input string called userinput. I'm trying to get my views.py file to check the database backend to see if any model object's `fbusername` attribute match the userinput entered. If something matches, then simply return the value for that fbusername attribute from the database. If it does not match, then execute some other code etc, but I can't seem to do the first step correctly because it always goes to the `else` condition even when I have prepopulated an object with the same fbusername attribute. Here is my if statement, I'd appreciate any help:

```
...
from app.models import facebookobject
...
def view_for_all_pages(request, userinput = 'userinput'):
    if userinput == facebookobject(fbusername=userinput):
        return render (request, "app/template.html", {"userinput": facebookobject(fbusername=userinput)})
    else:
        ....
        name = fbstring['name']
        ....
        return render (request, "app/template.html", {"url_param": name})
```

I can't get the first part correct. It always goes to the 'else' condition meaning that I can't get the userinput compared to each facebookusername attribute in the database. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Presumably `facebookobject` is a model class. So you are instantiating a new object from your input, and then checking if it is the same as your input? Of course it isn't, it's an object you just created. What *exactly*are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't query the database at all here. Just instantiating a `facebookobject` doesn't do a query: on the contrary, it's the first step in creating a new db entry.

You should use the well documented query API:

```
try:
    fb = facebookobject.objects.get(fbusername=user input)
except face book object.DoesNotExist:
    # code for no match
else:
    # code for match, do something with fb
```

You should do the tutorial, where all this is explained thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got it working. I didn't see the tutorial for the query API. I didn't know it existed. A quick run through got me all up to speed. Many thanks!